# Возникает предупреждение в yandex maps API: "Warning: The tag <ymaps> is unrecognized in this browser."

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, nextjs

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему с возникающим варнингом `yandex maps API` в `React` :

`Warning: The tag <ymaps> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.`.

Компонент `<YMap>` беру в соответствии с документацией:

```
const [ymaps3React] = await Promise.all([ymaps3.import('@yandex/ymaps3-reactify'), ymaps3.ready]);
const reactify = ymaps3React.reactify.bindTo(React, ReactDOM);
const {YMap, YMapDefaultSchemeLayer, YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer, YMapMarker, YMapControls} =
reactify.module(ymaps3);
```

Предупреждение возникает, когда в JSX пишу:

`<YMap location={LOCATION} ref={(x) => (map = x)}></YMap>`.

Понимаю, исходя из контекста предупреждения, что браузер не знает такого тега `<ymaps>` и что, если это реакт компонент, то его имя нужно писать с большой буквы.

Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы это предупреждение больше не возникало?

Answer (score 0):

Это ворнинг, который показывается только в dev-версии реакта. На функциональность влиять не должен.